# cakephp: saveAll is not working

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

The saveAll is not working can some one help me in finding what is the problem.I have included the controller's action, the array passed to saveAll and the model of it.

The controllers action containing the saveAll looks like the following-

```
public function add_customer_order() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                      -
                      -
                      -
                      -
                   $this->CustomerOrderItem->create();
                   if ($this->CustomerOrderItem->saveAll($customer_order_item)) {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('The customer order Items has been saved successfully.', 'default/flash_success');
                     }
                else {
                    $this->Session->setFlash('The customer order Items not been saved successfully.', 'default/flash_success');
                }
    }

}
```

The array $customer_order_item looks as follows-

```
array(
    'CustomerOrderItem' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'quantity' => '400',
            'unit_cost' => '77',
            'pending_quantity' => '400',
            'packaging_configuration_quantity' => '20',
            'exercise_duty_id' => '0',
            'tax_id' => '5',
            'customer_order_id' => '',
            'master_article_id' => '22'
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'quantity' => '200',
            'unit_cost' => '77',
            'pending_quantity' => '200',
            'packaging_configuration_quantity' => '20',
            'exercise_duty_id' => '0',
            'tax_id' => '5',
            'customer_order_id' => '',
            'master_article_id' => '25'
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'quantity' => '400',
            'unit_cost' => '77',
            'pending_quantity' => '400',
            'packaging_configuration_quantity' => '20',
            'exercise_duty_id' => '1',
            'tax_id' => '5',
            'customer_order_id' => '',
            'master_article_id' => '23'
        ),
        (int) 3 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'quantity' => '200',
            'unit_cost' => '77',
            'pending_quantity' => '200',
            'packaging_configuration_quantity' => '20',
            'exercise_duty_id' => '1',
            'tax_id' => '5',
            'customer_order_id' => '',
            'master_article_id' => '24'
        ),
        (int) 4 => array(
            'id' => '',
            'quantity' => '200',
            'unit_cost' => '77',
            'pending_quantity' => '200',
            'packaging_configuration_quantity' => '20',
            'exercise_duty_id' => '1',
            'tax_id' => '5',
            'customer_order_id' => '',
            'master_article_id' => '27'
        )
    )
)
```

The model looks as follows-

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * CustomerOrderItem Model
 *
 * @property CustomerOrder $CustomerOrder
 * @property MasterArticle $MasterArticle
 */
class CustomerOrderItem extends AppModel {

/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'customer_order_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'master_article_id' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'CustomerOrder' => array(
            'className' => 'CustomerOrder',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_order_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ),
        'MasterArticle' => array(
            'className' => 'MasterArticle',
            'foreignKey' => 'master_article_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: how not working ? any message ?

Comment: what about the customer_order_id value in your array..? why that is NULL?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure it is a data issue either due to validation or null in db.

1. debug the contents of `debug($this->request->data);`
2. debug the invalid fields if any `debug($this->Submission->invalidFields());`. Make sure you call this after you have issues `validates()` request or `saveAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if ($this->CustomerOrderItem->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
```

Comment: The array what I have posted is the formatted array that is derrived from $this->request->data

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove all the validation rules and then check again if error is still coming.if not then there must be issue with data validation rules or null value of 'customer_order_id'.